# Links about developing applications for practice on the android platform

Tags: android

Are there any links about developing applications for practice on the android platform.

Comment: Yes there are. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you download the SDK there are plenty of examples in there.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html) is a list of all the example apps and what they do.

Other than that, browse around the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html) site and absorb as much as you can

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Android site?

They have a [hello world-type introduction](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html).

If you don't know how to set up your environment, also check [the guide about installing and setting up your Android dev environment](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).